# Show code on a page with XMP within a container

Tags: html

I need to display some code on a page without parsing it - I can use XMP to do that but it doesn't seem to stay within the confines of the container it's located in?  Is there a way to make it fit within the width of the div?

http://codepen.io/r3dg3cko/pen/RKeBQb

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 100px; background: grey">
<XMP><img     src="/WVO/WVOITSD/Picture%20Library/Site%20Editing%20Guide%20Images/SEG14.png" style="max-width:100%; cursor:pointer"onclick="onClick(this)" class="modal-hover-opacity"></XMP>
</div>
```

Comment: [The `<xmp>` element is obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp) and shouldn't be used. Use the `<pre>` and `<code>` elements instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you inspect the nodes with your browser developer tools you'll see that both tags have indeed a 300px width. The problem is that contents overflow because they don't have line feeds (that's the default for `<pre>` and `<xmp>` tags).

You may want to play with the white space settings in the `<xmp>` tag, e.g.:

```
xmp{
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

([Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZLmQxw)).

As noted by Jordan, the tag has been deprecated for years and it's technically removed from HTML as for version 5. (I particularly only use it as quick debug trick to display variables from PHP while coding.) It's fairly easy to escape HTML tags in most programming languages.